# Use reflection to get entries from a list

Tags: java, reflection

I have a LinkedList of Strings

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList();
list.add("");
```

Using **Reflection**, how would I be able to get the **Field** object of list.get(0) and then set the field object with a value such as "Hello"?

Something like this:

```
Field field = //the field entry of list.get(0)
field.set() // set field with a string "Hello"
```

Comment: how can you get a field from a String object? list entries are in memory, they are not fields. sounds like an XY problem https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Annotations:

1. This is dangerous, because reflection is heavily implementation dependent.
2. This does not make much sense as a real-world solution. Java's big advantage is static compile-time checks, and this completely circumvents it. (Checks on container classes and variable types)
3. Also, it is slower and cumbersome.

### Solution:

Look at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java

We see that the Nodes are contained as such:

```
transient Node<E> first;
transient Node<E> last;
```

And the Node class is defined (see link above) as:

```
private static class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;
    Node<E> prev;

    Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
        this.item = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

So first we need a node, then its *item* value.

To iterate over elements, we will need to access the *next* variable.

Full Code:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LinkedListAccesReflection {



    public static void main(final String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        final LinkedList<String> theList = new LinkedList<>();
        theList.add("Item 1");
        theList.add("Item 2");
        theList.add("Item 3");

        // we have to base all on Object, instead of on LinkedList$Node, because we cannot address inner static private class
        // we could use runtime variable type checks, see comment below

        { // show first value
            final Object nodeFirst = getValueFromObject(theList, "first");
            final Object value = getValueFromObject(nodeFirst, "item");
            System.out.println("Access Value: " + value);
        }

        interateOverElements(theList);

        { // manipulate value 1
            final Object nodeFirst = getValueFromObject(theList, "first");
            setValueOfObject(nodeFirst, "item", "Bad cheated value");
            System.out.println("Manipulated the list.");
        }

        interateOverElements(theList);


        // if you wanna do some runtime class checks, you can use that code
        //          final Class<?> listClass = theList.getClass();
        //          final String innerNodeClassName = listClass.getName() + "$Node";
        //          final Class<?> innerNodeClass = Class.forName(innerNodeClassName);
    }

    private static void interateOverElements(final LinkedList<String> pTheList) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        System.out.println("Iterate Nodes:");
        Object current = getValueFromObject(pTheList, "first");
        while (current != null) {
            final Object value = getValueFromObject(current, "item");
            System.out.println("\t" + value);

            final Object nextNode = getValueFromObject(current, "next");
            current = nextNode;
        }
    }

    static public Object getValueFromObject(final Object pTheObject, final String pVarName) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        final Field listField = pTheObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(pVarName);
        listField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object nodeObject = listField.get(pTheObject);
        return nodeObject;
    }
    static public void setValueOfObject(final Object pTheObject, final String pVarName, final Object pValue) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        final Field listField = pTheObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(pVarName);
        listField.setAccessible(true);
        listField.set(pTheObject, pValue);
    }


}
```

Comment: Update: I also included setting a value. This is inherently and horrible unsafe though!

Comment: Thank you and much appreciated. Yes, I am perfectly aware of the fact that this is highly unsafe, but I am working on a requirement that would force us to use reflection to make the code generic. I therefore am researching on this. Once again, much appreciated.

Comment: By the way, `List` has a method `set(int index, T value)`. (It's better to just check if `obj instanceof List`)

Comment: @mang4521 Can you tell us what the actual problem is? Because in 99% of those cases where they say 'that would force us to use reflection', it's rather a bad design problem than a necessity. If you're talking generic serialization/persistence etc, I'm with you. The rest... never heard of a *real* problem requiring that manipulation.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn You are 100% right. In case we actually do have to use *Reflection*, `obj instanceof List` is dangerous. Because then you SEE that there's a check, but that check is not fully valid. Because List could also be `ArrayList` with its completely different implementation. So if we do check, then we need to make sure we're 100% there. Just to point out, in case someone actually tries.

Comment: The check is good enough if you use `list.set(0, newValue)`.

Comment: And who uses `LinkedList` in real life anyway…

Comment: @JohannesKuhn We have a requirement where there is an input object type [A complex object] and then there is an output object type [complex again]. We would like to set input fields onto the output without having to create any if else ladders.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I do have a follow up question. How would the implementation change if a LinkedList is replaced by an ```ArrayList```? An ArrayList would not have the "first" var name right? So how then would I be able to set the first entry of the ArrayList?

Comment: Use `list.set(0, "hello")`. Works with `LinkedList`, `ArrayList`, `Arrays.asList("")`...

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I am referring to setting the first element of the ArrayList using ```reflection```. Similar to your example above for LinkedList.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I followed the logic provided by you above and this is what I came up with ```final Field objectArrField = inputObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("elementData");
        objectArrField.setAccessible(true);
        Object[] objArr = {String.valueOf(valueToBeSet)};
        objectArrField.set(inputObject, objArr);```

Comment: That' if you wanna replace the whole array... If you wanna replace a single element, you could a) simply manipulate one index in the original array or b) create a copy of the original array, manipulate one element in there, set the whole new array, like you did in your last comment